# Must pass parameter number 4 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value' " al ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado desde mi codigo en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

tengo un problema al ejecutar mi procedimiento almacenado desde mi código me sale el siguiente error

> {"Must pass parameter number 4 and subsequent parameters as '@name =
> value'. }

no se que estoy haciendo mal dejo adjunto un fragmente de mi código , el cual contiene tres entrada de datos y una que es un out.

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@M", 16);
                    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@P", 1);
                    SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@SEC", "");
                    param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output ;
                    param3.Size = 50;
                    param3.DbType = DbType.String;


                    SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@NUM", "3242");
                    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
                    parameters.Add(param1);
                    parameters.Add(param2);
                    parameters.Add(param3);
                    parameters.Add(param4);


                     var resultadoConsulta =modelo.Database.SqlQuery<object>("EXEC procedimiento.almacenado @M ,@P,@SEC = @SEC OUTPUT,@NUM ", parameters.ToArray());
                    var x = resultadoConsulta.FirstOrDefault();
                    var valor = param3.Value.ToString();
```

en valor quiero que regrese el  SEC , porfa si alguien me puede ayudar con esto estaria agradecido

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en que cuando defines un parámetro como nominal, SQL Server espera que los siguientes parámetros sean nominales, y el parámetro num no lo es.

```
create procedure procedimiento_almacenado (@M int, @p int, @sec varchar(10) output, @num int)
as
begin

    set @sec = 'Resultado';

End
```

Nota: ¿Seguro que el procedimiento se llama `procedimiento` **punto** `almacenado`?

Desde TSQL, tu declaración de exec es tal que:

```
Declare @M int = 1;
Declare @p int= 2;
Declare @sec varchar(10)='';
declare @num int = 3242;

exec procedimiento_almacenado @m, @p, @sec=@sec out, @num

select @sec
```

[image: Error]

La solución es simple. O pones el parámetro @num=@num o quitas la definición de @sec=@sec out por @sec out

```
Declare @M int = 1;
Declare @p int= 2;
Declare @sec varchar(10)='';
declare @num int = 3242;

exec procedimiento_almacenado @m, @p, @sec=@sec out, @num=@num 

select @sec 

exec procedimiento_almacenado @m, @p,  @sec out, @num 

select @sec
```

[image: Result 2]

[image: Resultado parametros]

[Sql parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/specify-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15)